# Does it make sense to test ui components separately?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, user-interface, functional-testing

I'm working on a webform that has about 15 user controls, separated by context (comments, locations, members/leaders, etc).  
If each control can render individually (using real or test data), does it make sense to have a separate "functional" test page to test them in isolation or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense if you want to make a shallow test or if you want to the layout (i.e. with sample data etc.), or see if control places the provided content in the right place and so on, but if you want to test if the data loads properly, then test each control individually won't provide you all you need.

Comment: Right,  I would have seperate tests for the classes that get the data.